# Interface with Linux mouse driver

Tags: c, linux, architecture, linux-device-driver

How would one go about writing code that implements a mouse driver in Linux?  I believe that is the right way to phrase what I want to do.

For example, if I wanted to write code to make every left mouse click a right mouse click, how would I even begin to interface with my mouse?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is way too broad for Stackoverflow. Writing a driver is non-trivial and is not something that a SO question can teach from scratch. You'll have to do more research on your own and ask a more specific question. For linux driver development a good place to start is the [Linux Device Drivers](https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/) book. An alternative is not to write a device driver but use the [Linux input subsystem](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6429)

Comment: In Windows you can swap the mouse buttons in the Control Panel settings. I have seen some web pages suggesting similar can be done with Linux, without writing a new device driver.

Comment: you can open a file in `/dev/input/` to read input events. if you want to inject events back as a virtual input device, you can write to `/dev/uinput`. there are a lot of examples online.

Comment: Thanks- this is just what I was looking for.